# Redirect is adding trailing slash added to html file

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following redirect in my .htaccess file. The code is working properly when the URL without the trailing slash is used but when the trailing slash is added it is redirecting to the file and then adding a trailing slash causing a 404 error.

redirectmatch 301 ^/fishing/saltwater/?$ http://www.mydomain.com/fishing/saltwater.html

```
/fishing/saltwater redirects to /fishing/saltwater.html
```

BUT

```
/fishing/saltwater/ redirects to /fishing/saltwater.html/
```